# How to split a string into pairs of equal length with 0 in the empty positions in python?

Tags: python

I have a string, for example "6PH57VP3+PR " and I need to split it in order to get these strings:"6P00000000", "00H5000000", "00007V0000", "000000P300", "00000000PR".
Is there a simple python function that can do this?

Comment: the + there breaks the pattern though.  Is all the strings of form aabbccdd+ee?

Comment: What exactly are the rules for this?

Comment: @ChristianSloper yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always want to remove the `+` and the string is always the same length you could use a list comprehension.

```py
location_code = '6PH57VP3+PR'

location_code_list = ['0'*s+location_code.replace('+','')[s:s+2]+'0'*(8-s) 
                      for s in range(0, 10, 2)]

print(location_code_list)

""" output
['6P00000000', '00H5000000', '00007V0000', '000000P300', '00000000PR']
"""
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a simple function that do exactly this, but it is easy to make one:

```
def f(s):
    res = []

    #before +
    for i in range(0,len(s)-3,2):
        a = ['0']*len(s)
        a[i:i+2] = s[i:i+2]
        res.append("".join(a))

    # the last 2 after +
    a = ['0']*len(s)
    a[-2:] = s[-2:]
    res.append("".join(a))

    return res 

assert f('6PH57VP3+PR')  == ['6P000000000', '00H50000000', '00007V00000', '000000P3000', '000000000PR']
```